# Estimating the random effect structure and variance-covariance matrix for RRs from observational studies

Tags: multilevel-analysis, covariance, random-effects-model, covariance-matrix, relative-risk

long time reader, first time poster. Have found this community to be extremely helpful but alas have not had luck finding a previous question relating to this:

I am attempting to run a meta-regression on relative risks (RRs) using the *rma.mv* function within the *metafor* package. The outcome is *mortality*, and the exposure is *having a mental disorder* vs *not having a mental disorder*. The studies are observational, and will typically report outcomes for multiple mental disorders (e.g., the RR for depression, the RR for anxiety, etc.) and I wish to predict out pooled RRs for each mental disorder. Participants can meet criteria for multiple mental disorders, and the entire sample is used to estimate the RR for each mental disorder. I also have a couple of study methodology covariates to account for (percent female and study design). At the moment I have my rma.mv function set out as:

```
model <- rma.mv(log_rr, V, random = ~ 1 | as.factor(study_id),
                 mods = ~  as.factor(mental_disorder) + percent_female + as.factor(study_design),
                 data = dataset, method = "REML")
```

I have 2 questions:

**1. Should I set as.factor(mental_disorder) as an inner random effect `random = ~ as.factor(mental_disorder) | as.factor(study_id)`?** I got the idea from reading the [Berkey et al. (1998)](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998) example where there are multiple outcome measures from the same sample within each study. I thought this might be appropriate because participants can meet criteria for multiple mental disorders within the same study (and therefore be considered exposed for multiple RRs from that study). However in my case, the mental disorder type (depression, anxiety, etc.) is not the outcome, but is the exposure.

**2. What is the best method to estimate the variance-covariance matrix for RRs derived from observational data?**
I was originally following the [Gleser & Olkin (2009)](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:gleser2009) example to create the variance-covariance matrix for RRs, and also read Cooper et al. (2009) regarding this. However it seems that this method is for when the RRs are from study comparing multiple different treatments to a common control group. Because the control group is the 'shared' sample, the covariance is estimated from the control group as: `(1-P_c)/(N_c*P_c)` where `P_c` is proportion of the control group with outcome and `N_c` is the sample size of the control group.

In my example, the entire sample is used to estimate each RR. The only difference between each RR is whether they are considered having the mental disorder of interest or not (i.e., whether they move from cells a/b to c/d or vice versa in the standard 4x4 RR matrix). I initially set up a variance-covariance matrix where the covariance was `(1-P_nmd)/(N_nmd*P_nmd)` where `P_nmd` is proportion of the participants without the mental disorder that experienced mortality, and `N_nmd` is the sample size of the participants without the mental disorder. However because participants can be considered 'control' participants for some mental disorders and not others, the covariance is different for every RR and the matrix becomes asymetrical. Out of desperation, I chose the covariance estimated from the RR where the control sample size is the largest.

Then it hit me that every participant in the study is informing every RR. Is it appropriate then to instead estimate the covariance as `(1-P)/(N*P)` where `P` represents the proportion of ALL participants that experienced mortality and `N` is the entire sample size? If not, can someone suggest an alternative solution to my problem?

Thank you!

Damian